# What is a stub on PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

What is a stub on PCB and what is it used for? Stubs exist with PCB traces and also vias, why?

Comment: It seems that a stub causes problems with signal integrity as well, how come?

Answer (score 18):

They're used for impedance matching and filtering.

The image [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_element_filter) below shows different stripline features used to create various elements etched into a PCB with descriptions below.

[image]

> Some simple planar filter structures are shown in the first column. The second column shows the open-wire equivalent circuit for these structures. The third column is a semi-lumped element approximation where the elements marked K or J are impedance or admittance transformers respectively. The fourth column shows a lumped-element approximation making the further assumption that the impedance transformers are λ/4 transformers.
>
> (a) A short-circuit stub in parallel with the main line.
>
> (b) An open-circuit stub in parallel with the main line.
>
> (c) A short-circuit line coupled to the main line.
>
> (d) Coupled short-circuited lines.
>
> (e) Coupled open-circuited lines.
>
> Stripline vias, (the little silver connections on the ends), represent a strap through the board making connection with the ground plane underneath

If you're familiar with transmission lines then you'll recognize the purpose for these elements. If you're not familiar, it's a scary yet fascinating topic I recommend learning more about. It's the weird stuff about electricity. Know your enemy.

There is a bit more explanation in a [previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/83188/15805) I gave on your previous question on via reflections.

Comment: Heh heh, know your enemy +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer Samuel. I was getting confused because I saw stub on a PCB trace connected to a trace point for use with oscilloscope probe. I also saw stub that we get in a through hole via. Seeing it at different places made me confused what it is and what it meant. I have been exposed to tranmission line theory and do find it quite fascinating. It is sad that yet it is not taught to a good in depth level at universities.

Comment: @quantum231 I had a required course entirely about transmission lines in my undergrad at Oregon State University. It was quite comprehensive.

Comment: There's also the unintended PCB stubs to care for, e.g. vias with unused sections that act like stubs. See this link: http://www.polarinstruments.com/support/si/AP8166.html